# Get to parent folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm putting an DOMpdf creator in my Codeigniter application, but now i need to get an require_once to the parent folder. Somehow Codeigniter doesn't allow me to do this the "normal" way.

This is my require_once

```
require_once("../dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

How can I make this work in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
//APPPATH gives you path till application/ folder
require_once(APPPATH.'your_DOMpdf_file_path');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To load a config file in CodeIgniter, you can call the `$this->config->load()` method.

> To load one of your custom config files you will use the following
>   function within the controller that needs it:

```
$this->config->load('filename');
```

> Where filename is the name of your config file, without the .php file
>   extension.
>
> If you need to load multiple config files normally they will be merged
>   into one master config array. Name collisions can occur, however, if
>   you have identically named array indexes in different config files. To
>   avoid collisions you can set the second parameter to TRUE and each
>   config file will be stored in an array index corresponding to the name
>   of the config file. Example:

```
// Stored in an array with this prototype: $this->config['blog_settings'] = $config
    $this->config->load('blog_settings', TRUE);
```

> Please see the section entitled Fetching Config Items below to learn
>   how to retrieve config items set this way.
>
> The third parameter allows you to suppress errors in the event that a
>   config file does not exist:

```
$this->config->load('blog_settings', FALSE, TRUE);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html